# Set Timeout SOAP client (Zend Framework)

Tags: zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I'm requesting a webservice using SOAP for which I need to set a request timeout.

```
new Zend_Soap_Client(http://www.aaa.com/ws/Estimate.asmx?wsdl",
                       array('encoding' => 'UTF-8');
```

I have also tried passing `'connection_timeout'=>100` but it seems like "unknow SOAP client option". Please suggest a way I can set the set timeout.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to set the timeout with Zend_Framework:

If you have your SoapClient-Object like this:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client(http://www.aaa.com/ws/Estimate.asmx?wsdl", array('encoding' => 'UTF-8');
```

You can set the timeout for HTTP-Requests. The default timeout in PHP is 30 seconds. With the following code you can e.g. set it to 1 minute.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => 1000
        )
    )
);
$client->setStreamContext($context);
```

Found on [downlifesroad.com](http://www.downlifesroad.com/2010/07/06/zend-soap-client-timeout/)

Answer (score 3):

Connection timeout option is not supported, the code is present in Zend_Soap_Client but commented

```
// Not used now
            // case 'connection_timeout':
            //     $this->_connection_timeout = $value;
            //    break;
```

Comment: Then how will zend handles service time out issues.

Comment: @user641637 I guess you can extend Zend_Soap_Client and just redefine method setOptions(). Zend_Soap_Client uses [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) which supports timeout option so it should work if you define this option in your method

Answer (score 2):

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout',$seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested solution using ZendHttpClient and Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl.

```
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client($location);
    $adapter = new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl();
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);
    $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->_timeout);

    $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
    $client->setHeaders('Content-Type', $version == 2 ? 
        'application/soap+xml' : 'text/xml');
    $client->setHeaders('SOAPAction', $action);
```

The idea is that you send an http request with the SOAP envelope as string at the request.

Full gist code [here](https://gist.github.com/2654079)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using native PHP [SoapClient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) class...

```
$client = new SoapClient($url,
            array(
                'connection_timeout'=>'30'
            ));

$response = $client->wsMethod(array
                ('param'=>'value));
```

You can define the whole duration limit using

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', '30');
```

Before calling it.
Works like a charm... ;)

Comment: `Zend_Soap_Client` internally uses `SoapClient` but fixes also some known problems around that class. So it's better to use `Zend_Soap_Client`. I posted a solution.